# How to use ScrollView in Android?

Tags: android, scrollview

I have an XML layout file, but the text is more than fits into the screen size. What do I need to do in order to make a `ScrollView`?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="1" >

    <TableRow>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
            android:tint="#55ff0000"
            android:src="@drawable/icon" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="3dip"
            android:text="  Name " />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/name1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="Veer" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/age"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="3dip"
            android:text="  Age" />

        <TextView android:id="@+id/age1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="23" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/gender"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="3dip"
            android:text="  Gender" />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/gender1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="Male" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/profession"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="3dip"
            android:text="  Professsion" />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/profession1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="Mobile Developer" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/phone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="3dip"
            android:text="  Phone" />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/phone1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="03333736767" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="3dip"
            android:text="  Email" />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/email1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="veer.developer@gmail.com" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/hobby"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="3dip"
            android:text="  Hobby" />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/hobby1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="Play Games" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/ilike"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="3dip"
            android:text="  I like" />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/ilike1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="Java, Objective-c" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/idislike"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="3dip"
            android:text="  I dislike" />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/idislike1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="Microsoft" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/address"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="3dip"
            android:text="  Address" />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/address1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="Johar Mor" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 514, accepted):

Just make the top-level layout a ScrollView:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:stretchColumns="1">

        <!-- everything you already have -->

    </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Is it possible to give ScrollView under a ScrollView ??? Or to provide multiple scrollview in a same page ???

Comment: @TaritRay - Certainly having multiple ScrollViews on a screen is not an issue; the parent layout simply needs to be arranged so they all have room on the screen. As for one ScrollView inside another, that's difficult. Instead, the Android compatibility library has [NestedScrollView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html). There are lots of tutorials on the web for how to use NestedScrollView for that application.

Answer (score 78):

## How to use ScrollView

Using [`ScrollView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html) is not very difficult. You can just add one to your layout and put whatever you want to scroll inside. `ScrollView` only takes one child so if you want to put a few things inside then you should make the first thing be something like a `LinearLayout`.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- things to scroll -->

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

If you want to scroll things horizontally, then use a [`HorizontalScrollView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html).

## Making the content fill the screen

As is talked about in [this post](http://www.curious-creature.com/2010/08/15/scrollviews-handy-trick/), sometimes you want the `ScrollView` content to fill the screen. For example, if you had some buttons at the end of a readme. You want the buttons to always be at the end of the text and at bottom of the screen, even if the text doesn't scroll.

If the content scrolls, everything is fine. However, if the content is smaller than the size of the screen, the buttons are not at the bottom.

[image]

This can be solved with a combination of using `fillViewPort` on the `ScrollView` and using a layout weight on the content. Using `fillViewPort` makes the `ScrollView` fill the parent area. Setting the `layout_weight` on one of the views in the `LinearLayout` makes that view expand to fill any extra space.

[image]

Here is the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">                        <--- fillViewport

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview"
            android:layout_height="0dp"                <--- 
            android:layout_weight="1"                  <--- set layout_weight
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:padding="6dp"
            android:text="hello"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"       <--- wrap_content
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:drawable/bottom_bar"
            android:gravity="center_vertical">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Accept" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Refuse" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

*The idea for this answer came from a previous answer that is now deleted ([link for 10K users](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20090295/3681880)). The content of this answer is an update and adaptation of [this post](http://www.curious-creature.com/2010/08/15/scrollviews-handy-trick/).*

Comment: Its saved lot of time for me

Answer (score 33):

There are two options. You can make your entire layout to be scrollable or only the TextView to be scrollable.

For the first case,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:stretchColumns="1" >

            <TableRow>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon"
                    android:tint="#55ff0000" >
                </ImageView>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="3dip"
                    android:text="  Name " >
                </TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/name1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="Veer" >
                </TextView>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/age"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="3dip"
                    android:text="  Age" >
                </TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/age1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="23" >
                </TextView>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/gender"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="3dip"
                    android:text="  Gender" >
                </TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/gender1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="Male" >
                </TextView>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/profession"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="3dip"
                    android:text="  Professsion" >
                </TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/profession1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="Mobile Developer" >
                </TextView>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/phone"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="3dip"
                    android:text="  Phone" >
                </TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/phone1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="03333736767" >
                </TextView>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/email"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="3dip"
                    android:text="  Email" >
                </TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/email1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="veer.developer@gmail.com" >
                </TextView>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/hobby"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="3dip"
                    android:text="  Hobby" >
                </TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/hobby1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="Play Games" >
                </TextView>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/ilike"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="3dip"
                    android:text="  I like" >
                </TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/ilike1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="Java, Objective-c" >
                </TextView>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/idislike"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="3dip"
                    android:text="  I dislike" >
                </TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/idislike1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="Microsoft" >
                </TextView>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/address"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="3dip"
                    android:text="  Address" >
                </TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/address1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="Johar Mor" >
                </TextView>
            </TableRow>

            <Relativelayout>
            </Relativelayout>
        </TableLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

or, as I said you can use scrollView for TextView alone.

Comment: Where you end the scrollView like this </ScrollView>

Comment: Sorry my bad. I have edited the answer now. You have to end it in the last.

Comment: Worked for me. I needed to warp my LinearLayout in a ScrollView.

Comment: The TextView class also takes care of its own scrolling, so does not require a ScrollView, but using the two together is possible to achieve the effect of a text view within a larger container. Quoted from : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html

Answer (score 15):

A ***ScrollView*** is a special type of *FrameLayout* in that it allows users to scroll through a list of views that occupy more space than the physical display.I just add some attributes .

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:fillViewport="true"
     android:scrollbars = "vertical"
     android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
    >
    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:stretchColumns="1"
        >
        <!-- Add here which you want -->
    </TableLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 11):

As said above you can put it inside a `ScrollView`... and if you want the Scroll View to be horizontal put it inside `HorizontalScrollView`... and if you want your component (or layout) to support both put inside both of them like this:

```
  <HorizontalScrollView>
        <ScrollView>
            <!-- SOME THING -->
        </ScrollView>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

and with setting the `layout_width` and `layout_height` ofcourse.

Comment: +1 just for mentioning importance of setting layout_width and layout_height

Answer (score 4):

Put your TableLayout inside a ScrollView Layout.That will solve your problem.

Answer (score 4):

To scroll data in text view you can use this to your text view.
and add 
and for anything other layout you can just add scroll view on layout as people are saying above.

/**
android:scrollable=true at textview in xml layout.

```
TextView txtScroll = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt1);
        txtScroll.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

*//

Answer (score -6):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:stretchColumns="1" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <RadioGroup
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/butonSecim1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight=".50"
                    android:text="@string/buton1Text" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/butonSecim2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight=".50"
                    android:text="@string/buton2Text" />
            </RadioGroup>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/bilgiAlani"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:visibility="invisible" >

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/BilgiAlanitableRow2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/bilgiMesaji"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight=".100"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:gravity="left|top"
                        android:inputType="textMultiLine" />
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/metin4"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".100"
                android:text="deneme" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/metin5"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".100"
                android:text="deneme" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</ScrollView>
```