# ScrollView in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, scrollbar, scrollview, android-3.0-honeycomb

I am doing some stuff in Android 3.0 with fragments. In one of the fragments, I need the scroll bar. I tried using a `ScrollView`, but it does not give me a scroll bar for the fragment.

How do I get a scroll bar for a fragment?

Answer (score 4):

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

//enclose your code for contents of fragment here. This helped me to add scroll view to the fragment





</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found an example in the official Android resources: [FragmentLayout](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/FragmentLayout.html). The class DetailsFragment contains a ScrollView which contains a TextView.

I tried the example and it's working on 3.0 SDK Emulator.
If it doesn't fix your problem, can you give more details of your code ?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you might prefer to just implement the ScrollView in an XML layout file: [How to use ScrollView in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674341/how-to-use-scrollview-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Use ScrollView tags for only fragments, which you want to scroll.  It is working in my project.  This is just a suggestion because I don't know your project or what you want to scroll on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

ScrollView cannot be used in a Fragment, since you cannot inflate many fragments under the same parent. You could rather use RelativeLayout or LinearLayout and keep ScrollView as inner layout.

Also checkout the new FragmentLayout in `com.android.widget` folder.

Answer (score 0):

In Android studio right click your project and select `New` --> `Fragment` -->  `Scrolling fragment`, so get a new scrolling fragment

If you already have an existing fragment, just check that android studio generated code and change your fragment code like the generated one.

Hope this helped.

**Happy coding!**