# Textview scrolling not working

Tags: android, xml, layout, scroll, textview

I want to scroll text down and up vertically, incase the text to appear in the textview is longer than the space. 
However, the below  methods I tested, do not work.

1 - `tv1.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());`
Moreover, upon using this method, calls to `onFling()` method stop to work.

2 - using `<ScrollView>` in layout XML.
also, when using this method, calls to `onFling()` method stop to work.

```
<ScrollView
android:id="@+id/SCROLLER_ID"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
android:fillViewport="true">

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/TEXT_STATUS_ID"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"/>

</ScrollView>
```

my TextView in layout XML is the following.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2.26"
    android:background="@drawable/green"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

Answer (score 16):

You can't have a scrollable `View`, like `TextView` or `ListView`, inside a `ScrollView`.
So use your simple `TextView` inside a normal layout and add `android:scrollbars` property to it.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:lines="3"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
    android:fadeScrollbars="true"
    android:fadingEdge="vertical" />
```

In the `Activity` side you must write something like:

```
tv1.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

(Basically the same thing o described at your first point)

Comment: hi @yugidroid , I retried, it did not work. and once i apply the tv1.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod()); my onFling() methods which I use to swipe left/right stops to work.

Answer (score 3):

you can try it as:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"

    android:layout_height="fill_parent"

    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TEXT_STATUS_ID"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"/>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: do I have to use the <linearLayout ?

Comment: @DanJurgen, you do. Make a scrollable `TextView` inside a `ScrollView` won't work.

Comment: @yugidroid . I tried it, and it WORKS. however, the text is getting way too up or way too low. Is there any method that I can make it between two fixed lengths ? and whenever I get a new text there, the location (lets say very up) still applies to the new text.. I want it to be centered..

Comment: the onFling() methods, and the gestures work when you override the dispatchTouchEvent

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)
{
    super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);    
    return productGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(ev); 
    }

Answer (score 1):

```
<ScrollView
android:id="@+id/SCROLLER_ID"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/TEXT_STATUS_ID"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: hi @Danil. Unfortunately, it does not work. Long texts are not scrollable down and they are cut off. the onFling() method also does not work.

Comment: whats ur android version and what is your handset ?

Comment: i have several different devices. It doesn't important: its basic functionality. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674341/how-to-use-scrollview-in-android