# scroll edit texts inside android app issue

Tags: android

i have this xml layout here and the issue is i might have more than 15 editTexts, now, i tried to add a  but it said App stopped, maybe i put it the wrong way...
I just need to scroll the screen and see all edittexts..
Here is the xml file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

  <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Emer"
    />
  <EditText
        android:id="@+id/msgMbiemer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Mbiemer"
    />

  <EditText
        android:id="@+id/msgTelefon"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Nr. Telefoni"
    />



    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/msgAdresa"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Adresa"
    />



    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/msgOra"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Ora e Krijimit"
    />



    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/msgPer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Per ke?"
    />



    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/msgDyqan"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Dyqan"
    />



    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/msgStatusi"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Statusi"
    />


<ProgressBar
android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


<Button
android:id="@+id/button1"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Submit" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Just put this `LinearLayout` inside [scrollview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674341/how-to-use-scrollview-in-android).

Comment: could you please help me with the cod ei have?
i tried and still it says app has stopped...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:orientation="vertical" >    
       <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Emer"
       />
       <EditText
        android:id="@+id/msgMbiemer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Mbiemer"
       />    
       <EditText
        android:id="@+id/msgTelefon"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Nr. Telefoni"
       />    
       <EditText
        android:id="@+id/msgAdresa"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Adresa"
       />        
       <EditText
        android:id="@+id/msgOra"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Ora e Krijimit"
       />    
       <EditText
        android:id="@+id/msgPer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Per ke?"
       />     
       <EditText
        android:id="@+id/msgDyqan"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Dyqan"
       />        
       <EditText
        android:id="@+id/msgStatusi"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Statusi"
       />        
       <ProgressBar
         android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
         style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" />       
       <Button
         android:id="@+id/button1"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="Submit" />

       </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I hope this will help you.