# Keyboard hides my button Android

Tags: android

I have a very annoying problem, I have a screen with a button at the bottom and an edit text at the center, when I write in the edit text, the keyboard comes up and hides the button. 
I want that the button will be above the keyboard and follow it, but I dont want the background picture to shrink (This is what happened when I tried to put it in scrollview). 
If someone has an idea, that would be wonderful.

Comment: follow this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674341/how-to-use-scrollview-in-android

Comment: Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard

Comment: Also post some of the code you've written to try and do this.

Answer (score 1):

Just add following code to your manifest file at your activity tag

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateHidden"
```

For example

```
    <activity android:name="ACTIVITY_NAME" 
     android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateHidden"> 
    </activity>
```