# Android - How to scroll up and down all the screen

Tags: android, scroll, scrollview

I am new to android and I want to make an app that I can take some values with edittexts that has explanation text by them and calculate with a button at the end. But there are many variables that I want take and they don't fit on one screen. How can I make the screen scroll up and down just as the below example?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does anyone have a spare ScrollView?

Comment: Use ScrollView . Wrap your widget with ScrollView. Check [this]


  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674341/how-to-use-scrollview-in-android

Comment: Just with scrollView, do not forget to pack all your elements in a layout because ScrollView accepts just one child (I'm saying that because you're a beginner)