# Android ScrollView is not scrolling with a relative layout

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, scrollview

I have the following xml layout but my scrollview is not scrolling when I run the app. What am I doing wrong? I am trying to use a Relative layout in the scrollview instead of a Linear Layout Here is the xml..

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:id="@+id/main_title"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="180dp"
            android:layout_height="270dp"
            android:id="@+id/movie_poster"
            android:layout_weight="0.59"
            android:layout_below="@+id/main_title"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Ratings:"
            android:id="@+id/textView"

            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/movie_poster"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/movie_poster"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/movie_poster"
            android:layout_marginLeft="52dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="52dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text=" 6.5"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:id="@+id/movie_rating"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text=" 2015-01-01"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:id="@+id/movie_release_date"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView" />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:id="@+id/movie_description"
            android:layout_below="@+id/movie_poster"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Try android:fillViewport="true" for ScrollView.

Comment: See this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674341/how-to-use-scrollview-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you set the height of the **ScrollView** to `fill_parent`.
Try using a **LinearLayout** with weight so it fills the space left over from the other views.

If you do not want to set it to a specific height, you can also add

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```

to your ScrollView

Comment: I tried that and it's still not working. The root layout of my xml is Linear Layout, but for some reason when I paste the code stackoverflow cuts it out.