# My calculator project made in android studio doesn't scale

Tags: android, xml

I have just started a Calculator project in android studio(I
am newbie) and I figured a bug when I tried to debug in my phone.

The thing is that I searched a lot about dp, sp, fill_parent,
match_parent and things about scaling but I couldn't find an answer to
explain the problem.

This is a photo in my project content_main.xml:

[image]

and this is how it looks while debugging on an LG F60:

[image]

Can someone explain me what is wrong with the scaling? Thanks a lot!

My content_main.xml is:

```
<TextView
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="Pentru asta"
   android:id="@+id/textView"
   android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
   android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
   android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
   android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
   android:textSize="60sp"
   android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
   android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
   android:layout_marginBottom="40sp"
   android:layout_marginTop="40sp" />

<GridLayout
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
   android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
   android:layout_alignParentStart="false">

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="96sp"
    android:layout_height="72sp"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton5"[enter image description here][1]
    android:src="@drawable/one"
    android:padding="0sp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="96sp"
    android:layout_height="72sp"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    android:src="@drawable/one"
    android:padding="0sp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_row="1"
    android:layout_column="0" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="96sp"
    android:layout_height="72sp"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton7"
    android:src="@drawable/one"
    android:padding="0sp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_row="1"
    android:layout_column="1" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="96sp"
    android:layout_height="72sp"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton13"
    android:src="@drawable/one"
    android:padding="0sp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_row="1"
    android:layout_column="2" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="96sp"
    android:layout_height="72sp"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton17"
    android:src="@drawable/one"
    android:padding="0sp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_row="1"
    android:layout_column="3" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="96sp"
    android:layout_height="72sp"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:src="@drawable/one"
    android:padding="0sp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_row="2"
    android:layout_column="0" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="96sp"
    android:layout_height="72sp"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton8"
    android:src="@drawable/one"
    android:padding="0sp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_row="2"
    android:layout_column="1" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="96sp"
    android:layout_height="72sp"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton14"
    android:src="@drawable/one"
    android:padding="0sp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_row="2"
    android:layout_column="2" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="96sp"
    android:layout_height="72sp"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton18"
    android:src="@drawable/one"
    android:padding="0sp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_row="2"
    android:layout_column="3" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="96sp"
    android:layout_height="72sp"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
    android:src="@drawable/one"
    android:padding="0sp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_row="3"
    android:layout_column="0" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="96sp"
    android:layout_height="72sp"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton9"
    android:src="@drawable/one"
    android:padding="0sp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_row="3"
    android:layout_column="1" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="96sp"
    android:layout_height="72sp"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton15"
    android:src="@drawable/one"
    android:padding="0sp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_row="3"
    android:layout_column="2" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="96sp"
    android:layout_height="72sp"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton19"
    android:src="@drawable/one"
    android:padding="0sp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_row="3"
    android:layout_column="3" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="96sp"
    android:layout_height="72sp"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
    android:src="@drawable/one"
    android:padding="0sp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_row="4"
    android:layout_column="0" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="96sp"
    android:layout_height="72sp"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton6"
    android:src="@drawable/one"
    android:padding="0sp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:layout_column="1" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="96sp"
    android:layout_height="72sp"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton10"
    android:src="@drawable/one"
    android:padding="0sp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_row="4"
    android:layout_column="1" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="96sp"
    android:layout_height="72sp"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton11"
    android:src="@drawable/one"
    android:padding="0sp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:layout_column="2" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="96sp"
    android:layout_height="72sp"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton12"
    android:src="@drawable/one"
    android:padding="0sp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:layout_column="3" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="96sp"
    android:layout_height="72sp"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton16"
    android:src="@drawable/one"
    android:padding="0sp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_row="4"
    android:layout_column="2" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="96sp"
    android:layout_height="72sp"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton20"
    android:src="@drawable/one"
    android:padding="0sp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_row="4"
    android:layout_column="3" />
```

Comment: Do not use fixed sizes if you want it to be scalable. for layout_width and layout_height use wrap_content or match_parent

Answer (score 0):

With the exception of text size, always always always use dp unless you have a good reason not to. Here, almost all of the sp (excluding for text size) should be dp.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a scrollview on the top.

Check this topic for more info:

[How to use ScrollView in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674341/how-to-use-scrollview-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Try thinking about how you nest your xml views and always watch your `android:layout_width=""` & `android:layout_height=""`.
Especially in case of your `GridLayout`  you may want to consider android:layout_width="match_parent". Also what Viktor Yakunin mentioned in the comments.

Besides that either you did not provide all your XML or you missed to close your `GridLayout` tag.