# what is the best template to use if scrolling required in app

Tags: android-studio

I wish to create an app in android studio which will require scrolling. Which template should I select when I begin?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The template doesn't matter; add it manually:

---

But then, you have to use a `ScrollView`(See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674341/how-to-use-scrollview-in-android)). It is very simple, you just have to add an element and add everything you want to scroll through in it.

---

I hope I helped.

Comment: and to add a button so one may click on it to go to another screen

Comment: as it worked out got error messages trying to make signed apk

Comment: in the content_main.xml I put <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

</ScrollView>

Comment: and resulted in messages like missing classes appbarlayout; design,widget coordinate layout. confusing!

Comment: @Steve never make your `scrollview` the first object in your layout; it often causes bugs. Make the first object a `RelativeLayout`, and then after that add the `scrollview`. Remember to remove the `xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android";` from the `scrollview` and put it in the `relativelayout`.

Comment: took your advice. thank you so much! you know so much! maybe can you help me again? I wish to disable users clicking on my app then adding text. Do not want the text to be edited while viewed on the device.

Comment: @Steve Create a different question; helping you here is against the rules :)

Comment: Remember to mark my question as solved since it solved your question.