# How to bring the effect of scrolling on my activity

Tags: android, scrollview

How to bring this layout in scrolling form? I used ScrollView but it wasn't a help. It threw an exception.

I am new to Android. Would you show me what sort of rectification is required?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.exampl.home.mydisplaybill.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Select the IceCream flavor you want to order!"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"`enter code here`
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#1199CC"/>

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="   Vanilla for Rs30"
    android:textColor="#FF6352"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:id="@+id/checkBox"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:textSize="15sp" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/checkBox"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_marginRight="22dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="22dp"
    android:src="@drawable/vanilla"/>

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="   Butterscotch for Rs40"
    android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
    android:textColor="#FF6352"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="69dp"
    android:textSize="15sp"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/checkBox2"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageView"
    android:src="@drawable/butterscotch"
    />

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="   Pineapple for Rs40"
    android:id="@+id/checkBox3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="69dp"
    android:textColor="#FF6352"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="15sp"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/checkBox3"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageView"
    android:src="@drawable/pineapple1"/>
<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="   Pista for Rs50"
    android:id="@+id/checkBox4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox3"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="69dp"
    android:textColor="#FF6352"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="15sp"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/checkBox4"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageView"
    android:src="@drawable/pista1"/>
<CheckBox
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="   Mixedfruit for Rs60"
android:id="@+id/checkBox5"
android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox4"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
android:layout_marginTop="69dp"
android:textColor="#FF6352"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:textSize="15sp"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView5"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/checkBox5"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageView"
    android:src="@drawable/fruitmix"/>
<CheckBox
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="    Brownie for Rs80"
android:id="@+id/checkBox6"
android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox2"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
android:layout_marginTop="69dp"
android:textColor="#FF6352"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:textSize="15sp"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView6"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/checkBox3"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageView"
    android:src="@drawable/brownie"/>
```

Comment: What exception got thrown? Please post the logcat and your code with the scrollview

Comment: Provide full code of your xml file as well as logcat error and if possible then java side code.@Anshul

Comment: @Tapanparmar: I have rejected your edit - that is far too much of a change to this code. It's OK to tidy, but not to rewrite.

Comment: ok @halfer thanks for valuable guidance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look this will be helpful to you may be:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6674387/5476209

You have to put your main component Scrollview inside your layout xml file and be sure that you have must a single child in it ScrollView will not work with multiple child so take a relative or linear layout as parent put all your code in it and then put ScrollView as parent of all layout.

First understand concepts and please at least ask question after you not get similar questions like it. Also I found [a useful blog here](http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/android-scrollview-example), so please go through it.

Answer (score 1):

Put all the Text View and Check box in relative layout or linear layout .
Then put relative layout or linear layout in Scroll view it will work.
As Scroll view only works when there is only single child and you have multiple child. That's why it is giving you an error.

Hope this answer will help you.