# Screen rotation -Scroll View

Tags: android

[image]
HI,
In my android app,the emulator screen is rotating in landscape i didn't get the full view of a registration form. But in portrait mode it works perfectly. Please Look through it.Thanks in Advance. [image: portrait]

activity_main

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp"
android:weightSum="1">

<TextView
    android:text="Soil Test Based Nutrient Recommendations"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_weight="0.03" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:text="Crop"/>

<Spinner android:id="@+id/spinFood"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<TextView
    android:text="State"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:id="@+id/textView" />

<Spinner
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/spinner" />

<TextView
    android:text="Category"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView2" />

<Spinner
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/spinner2" />

<TextView
    android:text="Soil_Texture"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView3" />

<Spinner
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/spinner3" />

<TextView
    android:text="pH"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView4" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text=""
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText" />

<TextView
    android:text="Available Phosphorus"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView5" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text=""
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText2" />

<TextView
    android:text="Available Pottassium"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView6" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text=""
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText3" />



<Button
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button" />



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please post your xml file.

Comment: Do you use a ScrollView?

Comment: it will behave like that in landscape mode you have to use scrollview for it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use ScrollView in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674341/how-to-use-scrollview-in-android)

Comment: no, while using scroll view the app is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">    

<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp"
android:weightSum="1">

<TextView
    android:text="Soil Test Based Nutrient Recommendations"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_weight="0.03" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:text="Crop"/>

<Spinner android:id="@+id/spinFood"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<TextView
    android:text="State"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:id="@+id/textView" />

<Spinner
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/spinner" />

<TextView
    android:text="Category"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView2" />

<Spinner
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/spinner2" />

<TextView
    android:text="Soil_Texture"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView3" />

<Spinner
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/spinner3" />

<TextView
    android:text="pH"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView4" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text=""
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText" />

<TextView
    android:text="Available Phosphorus"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView5" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text=""
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText2" />

<TextView
    android:text="Available Pottassium"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView6" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text=""
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText3" />

<Button
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button" />

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Just wrap into `ScrollView` to Main `LinearLayout`

Comment: Thanks Rajesh... Its Working :)

Answer (score 1):

Add android:screenOrientation="portrait" to the activity you want to disable landscape mode.