# How scroll a layout view in android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, move

How to have multiple layouts (eg. Relative layouts) stacked one above other (each contains text and images regarding news) and move up/down or animate the top most layout  by scrolling action in android studio. Please see this screenshot to kmow what i am talking about 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MrqgKn7CEVuZwkMi8a6ZZB0MXxR3w10R/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674341/how-to-use-scrollview-in-android

Answer (score 0):

[image: the nter image description here]
in the new version of Android studio you can resize your preview layout by drag it. try this

Comment: I have added a screenshot link in the original question for better understanding of what i am trying to achieve. Can you guys please look into that

Comment: Just check the answer it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways to accomplish this.

Option 1: Dynamic content
- Utilize a Recycler view
- In your ViewHolders, use your RelativeLayouts as the layouts to inflate.

Option 2: Static Content
- Utilize a ScrollView root
- Utilize a vertical LinearLayout with height of wrap_content.
- Stack your RelativeLayouts.

Option 3: Another Static Content Option
- Utilize a ScrollView
- Utilize a RelativeLayout child
- Utilize your RelativeLayout childs inside the previous RelativeLayout and use layout_below in each of them.

(Extra info: Consider using ConstraintLayout or something else in place of RelativeLayout to avoid the double measurement issue with RelativeLayout)

Comment: I have added a screenshot link in the original question for better understanding of what i am trying to achieve. Can you please look into that

Comment: See Depth Page Transformer at this link. https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html#pagetransformer