# Why is my scrollview not working with this linearlayout?

Tags: android, scrollview

I Tried wrapping a scrollview around my LinearLayout with the ID of 6. which i need but it keeps messing everything up and it won't scroll for one single bit!

I already tried moving the scrollview around to see if others wrapped well with it, doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use ScrollView in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674341/how-to-use-scrollview-in-android)

Comment: Please add more details to your question from next time. Please refer this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6674387/10224384