# How to make my view scrollable on Android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, user-interface, scrollview

I create my xml view, and in the preview it seems good. But when i play on my emulator the elements doesn't fix, i think the emulator is too small.
So the solution i have tried is  setting the scrollbars to vertical:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

But it doesn´t take effect, i think it is only for lists or long texts
 [The preview of my aplication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sECUD.png)
[The real view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vz52l.png)

Comment: You have to use the Scrollview widget actually

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use ScrollView in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674341/how-to-use-scrollview-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a ScrollView as the parent layout, something like the following:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap your current code into a Scrollview and it will scroll if the text is too large or overflow.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollview"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</ScrollView>
```

Note that I am using `match_parent` which means it will take up all available space, so double check that you won't need something like `wrap_content` instead for the height / width.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that by default, a TextView is only a single line object.  If you want to show multiple lines, you need to define them in your xml layout:

```
android:maxLines="10"
android:lines="5"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try add android in your xml:

```
layout_marginBottom="16dp"
```

with this the TextView should be anleast 16dp from bottom or wrap it inside

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your TextView inside a ScrollView for this. However, take note that a ScrollView can only have one direct child inside it (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html). If you need to put more than one view inside a scroll view you can put them inside a LinearLayout and then put this LinearLayout inside the ScrollView, like Jagar pointed out https://stackoverflow.com/a/57928644/12019759