# Why does this android app does not display in full view in smaller screen device?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I'm using Relative Layout and I set the width and length to match_parent. It displays fine in Redmi k30 but in Pixel XL it only display up-to Delete Record, it does not display View All Record and scrolling also does not work.

I'm new to android and just starting layout designs, please advice. Thank you!

It should display like this:
[image]

But on Pixel XL the last button is missing:

[image]

XML layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#2196F3"
android:padding="10dp"
tools:context=".RUDActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="Please enter product ID to retrieve"
    android:textColor="#37474F"
    android:textSize="24dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/prodId"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/txtTitle"
    android:hint="Product ID"
    android:textColor="#37474F"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:textSize="24dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/prodId"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:hint="Name"
    android:textColor="#37474F"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:textSize="24dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/description"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/name"
    android:hint="Description"
    android:textColor="#37474F"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:textSize="24dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/price"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/description"
    android:hint="Price"
    android:textColor="#37474F"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:textSize="24dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/quantity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/price"
    android:hint="Quantity"
    android:textColor="#37474F"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:textSize="24dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSearch"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/quantity"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:text="Search Data"
    android:textSize="24dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/btnDelete"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:text="View All Record"
    android:textSize="24dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnUpdate"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/btnSearch"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:text="Update Record"
    android:textSize="24dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnDelete"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/btnUpdate"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:text="Delete Record"
    android:textSize="24dp" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to android..

Think of arranging 15 people in 5 rows of 3 in a dark room.
If you have to make them look the same whatever the dimensions of the room might be then the space cannot be the same.

Redmi and Pixel XL are high density and long devices.

You can use this library [Intuit SDK library](https://github.com/intuit/sdp)  for the dimensions. This library helps to automatically scale depending on the screen size.

Going forward However you have to use ConstraintLayout with matchConstraints and come up with a design idea that makes it look the same in most devices.

For eg: Making the upper form 1 section and the lower buttons another.
And instead of following a top-down approach make the form part stick to the top and the buttons part to the bottom.

3. For the scroll you have to use a ScrollView and wrap your layouts within it , Here is a good [Stackover FLow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674341/how-to-use-scrollview-in-android) to get started

Comment: Thank you, I learned a lot. I agree with you regarding Constraint Layout, the only reason I was using Relative Layout is because I was the tutorial.